# VK API friends.getRequests

Tags: vkontakte-api

Существует ли способ получить список моих заявок в друзья на стороннем сайте?
Следующий способ выдает ошибку:

```
$data = CJSON::decode($this->_apiCall('friends.getRequests', array(
    'count' => 1000, 'extended'=>0, 'need_mutual'=>0, 'out'=>1, 'sort'=>0, 'suggested'=>0
)), false);
```

User authorization failed: no access_token passed.

Comment: Вам же возвращается ошибка: Вы не авторизованы, нет подтверждающего-токена. Скорее всего вы его не отправляете или же забыли авторизоваться перед отправкой запроса.

Comment: Авторизация происходит с помощью перехода по ссылке

Comment: По ссылке: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
Где взять этот токен и куда его отправлять?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites   - 

4 пункт

Comment: Можно ли обойтись без создания приложения?

Comment: Почитайте тогда уж https://vk.com/dev/main и выберите то что Вам подходит, на сколько известно мне, необходимо в любом случае получать APPID, а для этого необходимо создать приложение

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На стороннем сайте получить список заявок в друзья **нельзя.**

Метод [friends.getRequests](https://vk.com/dev/friends.getRequests) доступен только [Standalone приложениям](https://vk.com/dev/standalone) – т.е. приложениям для мобильных, например.

В отличие от стороннего сайта, чтобы [авторизовать Standalone приложение](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile), потребуется программно получить доступ к адресной строке веб компонента, т.к. его перебросит в результате на адрес

```
https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=...
```

где вот этот токен вам и нужен для выполнения всех запросов к API.

Очень «кривой» **вариант обхода** – просить юзера скопировать эту адресную строку и вставить в форму на вашем сайте, чтобы сохранить токен. Это не работает на продакшн, для всех посетителей сайта (люди просто не станут так поступать в большинстве), но вы можете так авторизовать несколько своих аккаунтов, для себя.

В любом случае, вам понадобится «создать» (зарегистрировать) своё ВК-приложение, чтобы получить его app_id и secret – это всего [несколько кликов мышкой](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create).

Comment: Действительно, при использовании обычного подхода API отвечает ошибкой с кодом 10.

Comment: странно, ведь ошибка `#10` это «Внутренняя ошибка сервера – попробуйте повторить позже», как [пишут](https://vk.com/dev/errors).

Comment: Я думал, что под standalone подразумеваются все клиенты, кроме flash-приложений. Может-быть, у меня просто не получилось. Было бы хорошо, если кто-нибудь более опытный подтвердил, так ли это.

Comment: ВК различает три типа приложений: 1) сторонние сайты, 2) iframe/flash и 3) Standalone. Последним доступно практически всё. Сайтам – минимальный набор методов. Выбирается тип приложения при его [создании](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create).

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо создать приложение, для получения ***APPID***. Через него будет осуществляться авторизация. Плюс определите метод который Вам потребуется для реализации, это необходимо сделать до того как вы создадите приложение, так как необходимо будет выбрать какого плана приложение создавать.

Просмотреть какие есть методы можно [тут](https://vk.com/dev/main)